# segmentation fault in txt parsing C

Tags: c, gdb

Hi I'm trying to parse a txt file with 2 doubles in every line. At the first line there is an integer that is the total number of lines of the txt file. I have a Nx2 matrix of doubles COORD[NPOIN][2] and i want to put the first double of every txt line into COORD[IPOIN][0] and the second into COORD[IPOIN][1]. The part of the code below should enlighten you :D

```
COORD = (double**)malloc(NPOIN*sizeof(double*)); 

for(int i=0; i<NPOIN; i++)
{
  COORD[i] = (double*)malloc(NDIME*sizeof(double));
}

fin = fopen("coord", "r");
fgets(line, 256, fin);
NPOIN = atoi(line);
char *token;

for(IPOIN=0; IPOIN<NPOIN; IPOIN++)
{
   fgets(line, 256, fin);
   token = strtok(line," \t" );
   COORD[IPOIN][0] = atof(token); //line 891          
   token = strtok(NULL, " \t");
   COORD[IPOIN][1] = atof(token);

}
```

I compile the code,everything ok.But when I run it the gdb shows segmentation fault in line 891.Can anyone give some advice?I'm stuck!

Comment: You need to show the declaration and initialization of COORD

Comment: What is the value of IPOIN when you get the seg-fault? How is COORD allocated?

Comment: coord allocation: COORD = (double**)malloc(NPOIN*sizeof(double*));
 for(int i=0; i<NPOIN; i++){COORD[i] = (double*)malloc(NDIME*sizeof(double));}

Comment: Are your numbers separated by _space and tab_? Check `token` is not `NULL`.

Comment: they are separated by tab.

Comment: One possibility is that, `NPOIN = atoi(line);` is getting increased than the value which you used to allocate the memory. Hence it blows off in the for loop.

Comment: Following up on what @UchiaItachi said, you should do your `malloc`ing after you read NPOIN.

Answer (score 5):

**Here's how you debug with `printf`:**
*although you should really learn to step through your code with GDB or another debugger*

```
fin = fopen("coord", "r");
if (fin == NULL)  printf("failed to open\n");


fgets(line, 256, fin);
printf("Got first line as %s\n", line);

NPOIN = atoi(line);
printf("NPOIN is now %d\n", NPOIN);

char *token;

for(IPOIN=0; IPOIN<NPOIN; IPOIN++){
      fgets(line, 256, fin);
      printf("Got a line as %s\n", line);

      token = strtok(line," \t" );
      printf("Got token #1 %s\n", token);

      COORD[IPOIN][0] = atof(token); //line 891
      printf("Found float %f\n", COORD[IPOIN][0]);

      token = strtok(NULL, " \t");
      printf("Got token #2 %s\n", token);
      COORD[IPOIN][1] = atof(token);
      printf("Found float %f\n", COORD[IPOIN][1]);
}
```

Comment: I would add extra steps of saving the value of `atof(token)` to a double and printing that, before assigning it to `COORD[...]`

Comment: Ah, but how would you find the bad line (if such exists) if you don't print IPOIN? But seriously, this should become a wiki :)